# MongoDB $lookup with count , return if count grater zero

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collection which look like as follows.

**Service_category**

```
{
        "_id": "5feeacd031ccdf2f94f01b40",
        "name": "Category 1",
        "status": true,
        "createdAt": "2021-01-01T05:02:08.769Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T07:19:11.543Z",
},
{
        "_id": "5feeacd031ccdf2f94f01b43",
        "name": "Category 2",
        "status": true,
        "createdAt": "2021-01-01T05:02:08.769Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T07:19:11.543Z",
}
```

**Service**

```
{
        "_id": "5ffd5d4bc4967a1b10bf5022",
        "name": "Service1",
        "service_category_id": 5feeacd031ccdf2f94f01b40
},
{
        "_id": "5ffd5d4bc4967a1b10bf5023",
        "name": "Service2",
        "service_category_id": 5feeacd031ccdf2f94f01b40
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5feeacd031ccdf2f94f01b40",
    "name": "Category 1",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-01T05:02:08.769Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-02-01T07:19:11.543Z",
    "services": [
      {
        "_id": "5ffd5d4bc4967a1b10bf5022",
        "name": "Service1",
        "service_category_id": "5feeacd031ccdf2f94f01b40"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ffd5d4bc4967a1b10bf5023",
        "name": "Service2",
        "service_category_id": "5feeacd031ccdf2f94f01b40"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Return service category as per the following requirments.

1. Service Category along with services array if service exist in service category. which also mentioned in expected output.
2. Service Category status should be true.

Here is the query:

```
ServiceCategory.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'service_masters',
                        localField: '_id',
                        foreignField: 'service_category_id',
                        as: 'services'
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: {'$services.length': {$gt: 0}}
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following way to filter zero length array.

```js
ServiceCategory.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'service_masters',
                as: 'services',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'service_category_id'
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "services.0": {
                    $exists: true
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get an array length that way.

You will need a new field with the size to use `$gt`:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { $lookup: {
    // ...
  }},
  { $project: {
    _id: 1,
    name: 1,
    createdAt: 1,
    updatedAt: 1,
    services: 1,
    sizeOfServices: { $size: "$services" }
  }},
  { $match: { sizeOfServices: { $gt: 0 } } },
])
```

Comment: Thank you @Jérôme . it's perfect. now I want remove sizeOfServices from json result and include all fields of both collection without specifying it